# Arbitrage with freshly issued bonds

Tags: fixed-income, arbitrage, bond

I recently heard someone mention an arbitrage strategy involving selling freshly issued bonds and buying the "old batch" as it has shown that the liquidity in the fresh batch motivates/drives up these prices though everything else is equal. It was supposedly used extensively by Long-term Capital Management (LTCM) in the 90ies with extreme leverage and is common knowledge in the industry.

What is the phenomena called and where can I read more about it? Papers with examples and data are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called on the run/off the run arbitrage, a type of convergence trade. The basic idea is that as the liquidity premium disappears for the on-the-run issue, the price will fall and converge to the price of previous issues. Here are a couple papers -

http://people.stern.nyu.edu/lpederse/courses/LAP/papers/SearchBargaining/VayanosWeill.pdf
http://webuser.bus.umich.edu/ppasquar/onofftherun.pdf